# Spark dataframe filter both nulls and spaces

Tags: scala, apache-spark-sql

I have a spark dataframe for which I need to filter nulls and spaces for a particular column.

Lets say dataframe has two columns. col2 has both nulls and also blanks.

```
col1   col2
1      abc
2      null
3      null
4   
5      def
```

I want to apply a filter out the records which have col2 as nulls or blanks.
Can any one please help on this.

Version:
Spark1.6.2
Scala 2.10

Comment: I am able to filter out nulls and blanks separately like below.                                                                                                          `val df2 = df.filter("col2!= ''").filter(col("col2").isNotNull===true)`

Comment: But I want to include both the conditions in same filter expression

Comment: @srinivas the column on which I want to apply filter is same, as per my comment above

Comment: can you pls edit your comment.

Comment: It's more SQL way!  `val df2 = df.filter("col2 != ''  AND col2 is not null")`

Comment: @Ramesh does my post answer your question? If so please accept it

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The standard logical operators are defined on Spark `Column`s:

```
scala> val myDF = Seq((1, "abc"),(2,null),(3,null),(4, ""),(5,"def")).toDF("col1", "col2")
myDF: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [col1: int, col2: string]

scala> myDF.show
+----+----+
|col1|col2|
+----+----+
|   1| abc|
|   2|null|
|   3|null|
|   4|    |
|   5| def|
+----+----+


scala> myDF.filter(($"col2" =!= "") && ($"col2".isNotNull)).show
+----+----+
|col1|col2|
+----+----+
|   1| abc|
|   5| def|
+----+----+
```

Note: depending on your Spark version you will need `!==` or `=!=` (the latter is the more current option).

If you had `n` conditions to be met I would probably use a list to reduce the boolean columns together:

```
val conds = List(myDF("a").contains("x"), myDF("b") =!= "y", myDF("c") > 2)

val filtered = myDF.filter(conds.reduce(_&&_))
```